# Vim doesn't change the directory in the title bar when the working directory is changed

Tags: macos, terminal, vim

I have only the `Working directory or document` and `Active process name` preferences checked for Terminal window titles. Then in VIM I use a custom `titlestring`. The title bar is displayed as "<directory `vim` was executed in> — <custom `titlestring`> — vim". The problem is that when I change the current working directory in Vim, the first part of the title bar doesn't update to the new directory. It just remains as whatever directory `vim` was exectued from.

Is there a way to update the first part of the Terminal's title bar such that when the Vim working directory is changed it is as well?

Comment: what does this command `:set titlestring?` return?

Comment: @VictorS. I've since stopped using `titlestring`, and switched to using `set icon` and `iconstring`. Using `iconstring` doesn't fix the directory changing problem, but fixed whatever problem I was faced with when I decided to use it. Don't remember what it was. At the moment my title bar still reads exactly as it is expressed in the OP, but is accomplished using `iconstring`. At the moment `:set titlestring?` returns "titlestring=". And `set iconstring?` returns "iconstring=%f".

Comment: Perhaps the [autochdir](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27autochdir%27) option can help solve the problem.

Comment: @VictorS. It might solve the title bar problem, but introduces its own problems; namely, changing my working directory implicitly and obsoleting the relative path functionality provided by `iconstring`. At the moment my Vim work flow is based on the assumption that the working directory won't change on its own. Enabling it to do so may result in unexpected behavior. And I depend on the relativepath of `iconstring` for giving me context in regards to where I am in the file system.

Comment: Even if `autochdir` managed to update the title bar with the correct working directory, every relative path from thereon out would then just be the name of the file, removing all context other than that provided by the name of the directory; which I find to be unreliable as its not uncommon for me to use identical directory names in completely different file hierarchies.